# Div loads and disappears on asp.net PageLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have a div that I want to appear based on user input (works), however this div will appear and then hide itself on page load, because the javascript simply tells this Div to appear based on user input , and the input is defaulted to the option which causes the div to hide.  I am including the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function HideUnhide() {
        if (!$("#RadioButtonInput").attr("checked")) {
            $("#hideableDiv").fadeOut(200);
        } else {
            $("#hideableDiv").fadeIn(200);
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        //initial hide/unhide
        HideUnhide();
        //click triggered hide/unhide
        $(".RadioButtonID > input").click(
            function (event) {
                alert('click');
                HideUnhide();
            }
        );
    });
```

The RadioButton is binded to a SQL value in the website which stores session data, so it can't just "always be hidden" when the page loads, but it's visually annoying to watch this div be present and then disappear based on the data binding.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If the div is hidden on page load, is there any way to make it visible before another page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the server side code that writes out the HTML for the div, test the SQL value and if it should be hidden, then add a style attribute of `style="display:none"` to the HTML.

Comment: style="display:none" can be fixed at page load since Javascript will change the display upon page load.  Works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the initial visibility on the server side. Set the div to `runat="server"`, and right after you set the Checked property of the button, do this:

```
myDiv.Style.Add("display", (myButton.Checked ? "block" : "none"));
```